# how to exit when I return laravel Validation?

Tags: laravel, validation, switch-statement, laravel-validation

i' new to laravel here I have created a registration API and private function for validation but not show validation.

that is my validation function

```
`private function validateInfo($request, $toValidate) {

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $toValidate);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $errors = $validator->errors()->toArray();
            $values = array_values($errors);
            $arr = [];
            foreach ($values as $errorlst)
                array_push($arr, $errorlst[0]);
            $error = implode(',', $arr);
            return response()->json(['error' => true, 'message' => $error], 400);
            exit;
        }
    }`
```

call function under switch case :-

```
 switch ($request->user_type) :
            case "teacher":
                $this->validateInfo($request, [
                    'first_name' => 'required',
                    'last_name' => 'required',
                    'telephone' => 'required',
                    'country' => 'required',
                    'date_of_birth' => 'required|date',
                    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
                    'password' => 'required|min:6',
                ]);
                break;
            case "student" :
                $this->validateInfo($request, [
                    'first_name' => 'required',
                    'last_name' => 'required',
                    'telephone' => 'required',
                    'country' => 'required',
                    'date_of_birth' => 'required|date',
                    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
                    'password' => 'required|min:6',
                ]);
                break;
        endswitch;
```

it is not showing validation error. Any Mistake?
Thank You

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you are never returning what is returned from those method calls

Comment: thanks @lagbox but how can I return error it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this you can create a form request to validate your request.

```
class UserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator) {
        throw new HttpResponseException(
                    response()->json([
                        "message" => implode(',',$validator->errors()->all())
                    ], 422));
    }

    public function rules() {
        return  [
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'telephone' => 'required',
            'country' => 'required',
            'date_of_birth' => 'required|date',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Please check [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to return For Display Like

```
switch ($request->user_type) :
            case "teacher":
              return $this->validateInfo($request, [
                    'first_name' => 'required',
                    'last_name' => 'required',
                    'telephone' => 'required',
                    'country' => 'required',
                    'date_of_birth' => 'required|date',
                    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
                    'password' => 'required|min:6',
                ]);
                break;
            case "student" :
              return $this->validateInfo($request, [
                    'first_name' => 'required',
                    'last_name' => 'required',
                    'telephone' => 'required',
                    'country' => 'required',
                    'date_of_birth' => 'required|date',
                    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
                    'password' => 'required|min:6',
                ]);
                break;
        endswitch;
```